# Page numbering problem

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I use `\pagenumbering{roman}` for several pages in my `\documentclass{report}`.  I display my `\tableofcontents`, and then switch to `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. However, my table of contents is two pages long, and on the second page, the report switches to the arabic page numbering. Not sure why, and don't know how to fix.

To recap, my document looks like:

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{arabic}
% content
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just insert `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` after `\tableofcontents`.

So LaTeX recognizes that the new numbering has to start on the new page. Macro `\clearpage` starts a new page after printing not jet printed floats pending . `\cleardoublepage` starts the new page on thr right side (odd page number).